# Why mapping enter to nop makes the last search to be repeated?

Tags: key-bindings

I use the enter key as my leader:

```
nnoremap <cr> <nop> " To avoid moving the cursor
let mapleader="\<enter>"
```

So far so good. To have the same behavior on Dirvish I need to remap enter to `<nop>` again, otherwise when I press it, it navigates to the path under the cursor (which I don't need because `gf` is already burned in my brain):

```
augroup DirvishSetUp
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType dirvish
        \ nnoremap <buffer> <cr> <nop> |
        \ nnoremap <buffer> <silent> gf :call dirvish#open('edit', 0)<cr>
augroup END
```

It works as expected, except for an annoying little detail: If I searched something previously, on any buffer, and press the enter key on the Dirvish one and wait, the last search gets repeated. `:nmap` shows the following for `<cr>`:

```
n <CR> *@<nop><Space>
n <CR> * <Nop>
```

Why is this happening? (Not sure if relevant, but this is on Neovim 0.4.3)

Comment: I'm too lazy to investigate properly, but does removing the space from the end of this line fix the issue? `\ nnoremap <buffer> <cr> <nop>|` Does doing so change the output of `nmap <cr>`?

Comment: Yes, the issue is the trailing space which removes the special meaning of `<nop>`.  Remove it; otherwise `<nop>` is no longer handled like a no-op, but as a sequence of literal keys (`<`, `n`, `o`, `p`, `>`).

Comment: Yeah, that was the issue  Is it documented somewhere? `:h <Nop>` says nothing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem, as [user938271 explains](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/25132/why-mapping-enter-to-nop-makes-the-last-search-to-be-repeated-on-dirvish-buffers#comment43982_25132), is that by inadvertently including a space in the `{rhs}` of your mapping, you prevent `<nop>` from acting like a no-op, and instead it becomes a literal string of keystrokes: `<`, `n`, `o`, `p`, `>`.

In the resulting mapping, The `<` does nothing, and the following `n` repeats the last search.

This behaviour can be inferred from the documentation for `<Nop>`:

> An easier way to get a mapping that doesn't produce anything, is to use
>   "<Nop>" for the {rhs}.

Note that it doesn't say "**in** the `{rhs}`", but instead "**for** the {rhs}". This implies that if the {rhs} is not *exactly* `<Nop>`, but instead *includes* `<Nop>`, the special behaviour will not be triggered. (This wording could probably be improved, and I'm sure Bram would welcome a pull request for this.)

The space is included in the mapping is the one between the `<nop>` and the bar: `|`. Vim includes this in the mapping because it has no way of knowing this isn't what you intend. Thus, to fix the issue, change that line to:

```
\ nnoremap <buffer> <cr> <nop>|
```

Note that there are three clues that this is what was happening in the output of `:nmap <CR>`:

1. In the first, buffer-local, mapping, `<Space>` is included,
2. In that mapping the output has a lower-cased `<nop>` (what you typed) instead of the upper-cased `<Nop>` (Vim's notation for the special feature).
3. This is not visible in the paste, but it is inside Vim: the `<nop>` in the first mapping is highlighted differently from the `<Nop>` in the second one. The latter is has special highlighting to indicate it is *not* a series of keystrokes, but instead a single `<Nop>`.